# How to increment numbers in hlsl

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, hlsl, compute-shader

I'm new to shaders and I have no idea how to increment numbers in compute shader (HLSL).

```
groupshared uint i = 0;

#pragma kernel CSMain
[numthreads(8,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
   if(some_condition)
   {
      i++;
   }
   if(i == 10) do_something();
}
```

It's obvious the above code doesn't work. i++ causes race conditions (btw I learned about race condition few hours ago).
I had partial success with RWStructuredBuffer.

```
RWStructuredBuffer<int> i;

#pragma kernel CSMain
[numthreads(8,1,1)]
void CSMain (uint3 id : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
   if(some_condition)
   {
       int value_before_increment = i.IncrementCounter();
   }

   // if(i == 10) do_something();
   // Can't access the value of i without continuous increment
}
```

I Read some MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-cs-atomic-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and either their docs sucks or my braincells sucks. It would be really helpful if you could provide some beginner friendly blogs or articles or help me out in the answers. I know asking article recommendation at Stack overflow is not allowed but experienced people can guide the path.

Answer (score 0):

[Atomic Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/direct3d11/direct3d-11-advanced-stages-cs-atomic-functions?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> To access a new resource type or shared memory, use an interlocked
> intrinsic function. Interlocked functions are guaranteed to operate
> atomically. That is, they are guaranteed to occur in the order
> programmed.

You should use `InterlockedAdd` function.

Comment: A simple example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are confused between i (here a buffer, named like a variable, which created your mistake) and its contents and.or a variable

The line
if(i == 10) do_something();

should be

```
if(i[id.x] == 10) do_something();
```

OR rather in your case

```
if(i[value_before_increment] == 10) do_something();
```

OR

```
if(value_before_increment == 10) do_something();
```